# getting a violation error while copying entities

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

i have below entity project weather having below structure

```
public class ProjectWeather
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Project")]
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    [GraphQLIgnore]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WeatherStation")]
    public string WeatherStationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and i have other entity `project` and structure is looks like as below

```
public class Project : PatchEntityProperties
{
    [Key, GraphQLNonNullType]
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    public ProjectWeather Weather { get; set; } = new ();
}
```

what i am trying to do is copying one project info into other using the below code

```
   var cloneOfSourceProject = dbContext.Projects
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(a => a.ProjectNumber == sourceProjectNumber)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    // Tracked so we can remove existing project before adding copied entity
    var targetProject = dbContext.Projects
        .Where(a => a.ProjectNumber == targetProjectNumber)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (cloneOfSourceProject == default)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The project with project number '{sourceProjectNumber}' does not exist; an invalid project cannot be copied.");
    }
    
    string targetProjectName;
    if (targetProject == default)
    {
        targetProjectName = dbContext.Projects.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.Number == targetProjectNumber).SingleOrDefault()?.Name ?? "";
    }
    else
    {
        targetProjectName = targetProject.Name;
        dbContext.Remove(targetProject);
    }

    cloneOfSourceProject.ProjectNumber = targetProjectNumber;
    cloneOfSourceProject.Name = targetProjectName;
    dbContext.Add(cloneOfSourceProject);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

but getting an error on duplicate key value violates unique constraint on PK_projectweather on project weather and i am not sure how to overcome that error, is there anything wrong with the above code. I am using EFcore with postgresql.

Could any one please let me know any idea on this, many thanks in advance.

Comment: You're creating "cloneOfSourceProject" which has the same ID as the source project, without removing the source project. Either remove the source project, change the ID, or create the clone as a new object and simply copy the fields from the source project over to it.

Comment: sorry for wording, there is no clone of source and i am actually getting source project only using sourceProjectNumber

Comment: You're right, sorry, I missed the fact that ProjectNumber is the ID and you're changing it. Maybe try creating a new object anyway instead of saving the object which was the result of a query?

Comment: You should add the original error message in the post. Just curious, why are you querying for target project a second time inside `if (targetProject == default)`?

Comment: @atiyar original message is this `duplicate key value violates unique constraint on PK_projectweather on project weather`

Comment: @EnigmaState The issue is occurring because when you deleted `targetProject`, its related `ProjectWeather` didn't get deleted. Do you want the related `ProjectWeather` to get deleted when you delete the `targetProject`? Or do you want to assign the `targetProject`'s `ProjectWeather` to the `cloneOfSourceProject`?

Comment: I want to assign the target'sprojectweather to cloneofsource project

Comment: @EnigmaState Have you done any manual configuration for the `Project` and the `ProjectWeather` in the `OnModelCreating` method of the `DbContext`?

Comment: @atiyar  No , there is no manual configuration

Comment: @EnigmaState Its a bit confusing - you are trying to copy `target`'s properties (including primary key) to the `source`, and you also want `target`'s `ProjectWeather` to be assigned to `source`. Don't you think you can achieve the same result by just deleting the `source`. I'd suggest you add an `Edit` to the post clearly describing what you are trying to achieve, what is the final result of this operation you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have an idea of what might be going on. When you query into `cloneOfSourceProject`, you're specifying `AsNoTracking()`. This means that the `ProjectWeather` object attached to the Project you're querying is returned as well, but EF Core is not tracking its identity. Then you change the Project's `ProjectNumber` and save it, and so EF Core tries saving the whole object, along with its `ProjectWeather` (whose `ProjectNumber` was unchanged). That results in postgres writing a new `ProjectWeather` row with a key that already exists, and thus an exception.

If that's correct, you should be able to solve the issue simply by setting the `ProjectWeather`'s key to the new `ProjectNumber` before saving the project:

```cs
cloneOfSourceProject.Weather.ProjectNumber = targetProjectNumber;
```

Comment: Yeah that is correct but how do you mean to remove the entity from project weather

Comment: Added a line of code in my answer to explain what I mean

Comment: sorry still getting the same error, I put this line before saving the entity like `cloneOfSourceProject.ProjectNumber = targetProjectNumber;
    cloneOfSourceProject.Name = targetProjectName;
 cloneOfSourceProject.Weather.ProjectNumber = targetProjectNumber;`

Comment: or do i need to delete the existing project number in project weather and while inserting new one it does automatically

Comment: Shoot. Can you confirm that the duplicate key it's complaining about is in fact the `sourceProjectNumber`?

Comment: suppose i am copying project number "2000" to "9999" that means there is already data in projectweather on "9999" so with the above operation i am trying to insert the same 9999 again into projectweather and i think that might  be the issue

Comment: sorry its about the targetproject number

Comment: there is already data exists about targetprojectnumber in projectweather station

Comment: I am removing the targetprojectnumber record if it exists so do i need to delete a record reference  from projectweather as well related to targetprojectnumber

Comment: Yeah, that sounds likely!

Comment: how can i do that because it is key i believe

Comment: `dbContext.Remove(targetProject.Weather);` before removing the project?